# Update/Add options in the OptionMenu using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to update the options of a option Menu
As for example, there are labels that increments with clicking the button. So i want that label to shows as the options in the Option Menu

*** The code is edited now and is working fine. Is there any other way of doing it***

```
count=1
def LabelButton(self):
    x=Label(self,text="Count(%s)"%count)
    x.config(text="Count(%s)"%count)
    x.grid(column=0,row=0)
    count=count+1

def OpMenu(self):
    counter=list(range(count))
    options=[]
    for i in x:
        options.append("Count(%s)"%str(i+1))
    variable=StringVar()
    y=OptionMenu(self,variable,options)
    y.grid(column=0,row=1)
```

I am not sure the how to write for ***options***

1. I want it to display as options=[Count(1),Count(2),Count(3)].
2. And the optionMenu should update and should show all the options

Comment: What have you tried so far? What do you get? [Please post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

You are not adding count to your options array, you are assigning your array a scalar variable

Comment: I have edited my code and its working fine now :) Is there any other way of doing it